# Angular: Allow selection from only one group in drop-down list bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using [*bootstrap-select*](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for drop-down selection with angular. What I want to actually do is to allow selection only from one group(suppose a user selects *CS1607* from group *Ground*, the then selection from the other groups should be disabled and only selection from *Ground* is allowed then).

```
 $scope.course = [{
    id: "Ground",
    code: ['CS1607','SD90','EE11','PO213']
  }, {
    id: "First",
    code: ['PH006','EE2131','Aq122']
  }, {
    id: "Second",
    code: ['CSB-9','AA22']
  }];
```

I know, I have to use angular watchers for the changes. I tried a lot but could not get the desired result. [Here is my version of code.](http://codepen.io/kunalsharma12422/pen/xOEJZE)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would link each select to a model (`ng-model`) and disable each select whenever the models of the other two are not null. Something like (for select_1):

```
...ng-if="!select_2_Value && !select_3_Value"...
```